# Set the Id or Name of Kendo Window client side (dynamic), without re-creating the window

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I have a 'reusable' kendo window, and I want to set the Id/Name property of the window dynamically. How to do that?

I say Id/Name, because on server-side the property is called 'Name'

(e.g. `Kendo().Window().Name('windowName')`)

, but client side the attribute holding the value is 'id'

(e.g.: `<div id="windowName" class="k-window-content k-content" style="visibility: visible;" data-role="window"`)

i tried using:

```
.setOptions({name:name});

.setOptions({id:name});
```

and `setOptions({title:title});` with  `$("span:contains('" + title + "')").closest('.k-window-content');`

without success.

Basically the workaround i am trying to achieve is to get that 'k-window-content' div and set the 'id' with jQuery. If there is better way, I will be happy.

Comment: What is your reasoning for wanting to rename the ID of your window? If it's a reusable window, you just have one ID, grab the window handle from that ID and set different content. ID never needs to change.

Comment: It turned out the .Name() property is actually adding the Id to the Content, and later, if you change the content, the Id is gone, and the JS code can no longer find the reference to the window. Creating the window in JS and setting dummy content, creates a window without Id. I fixed it by adding a div with Id in the initial content. Will write the response later.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the .Name() property is actually adding the Id to the Content, and later, if you change the content, the Id is gone, and the JS code can no longer find the reference to the window. Creating the window in JS and setting dummy content, creates a window without Id. I fixed it by adding a div with Id in the initial content.